# Using the Web Service Consumer with Mule CE

Tags: web-services, http, mule, cxf

I'm in the process of migrating my cxf jaxws client to use the new HTTP connector. The mule docs say to do this:

```
<cxf:jaxws-client
     clientClass="org.apache.hello_world_soap_http.SOAPService"
     port="SoapPort"
     wsdlLocation="classpath:/wsdl/hello_world.wsdl"
     operation="greetMe"/>
<outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:63081/services/greeter"/>
```

but isn't this still using the old http implementation?

Next I attempted to convert it to use Web Service Consumer. All the examples I've seen use the DataMapper but this is not available for Mule CE.

Without the DataMapper I get the following error when running my app:

An invalid return type "interface javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader" was specified for transformer "JAXBMarshallerTransformer" (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
    at org.mule.module.xml.transformer.jaxb.JAXBMarshallerTransformer.doTransform(JAXBMarshallerTransformer.java:125)

Is the Web Service Consumer intended to only be used with the DataMapper? How do I use it without the DataMapper? What type of object do I send Web Service Consumer if not a jaxb object?

Is there a way to use cxf jaxws-client with the new http request-config?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the JAXB object to a string resolved the error.

Comment: still does not clear for me how to pass  param to Web Service Consumir. If you can give an example,  I'll be thankful! Here my question another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34662385/web-service-consumer-anypoint-studio-ce-runtime-how-to-pass-params